# How to make a single row collection view that scrolls horizontally but is fixed vertically?

Tags: ios

Im trying to make a `UICollectionView` that is 1 x N that scrolls horizontally but is locked vertically so it does not move vertically at all.

Any ideas or pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the flow layout, and set the scroll direction property to horizontal.

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/scrollDirection).

Comment: @reza_khalafi that's a... helpful comment. Can you add more detail?

Comment: does not work for me

Answer (score 21):

Use flow layout and set scroll direction to horizontal to fix your problem.

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 - 10, height: 190)
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
mainHomeCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
```

Comment: So funny that setting the scrollDirection property to .horizontal in IB doesn't work well as expected for horizontal page view(items added not in the right, but lower side). Only after setting it on source code it started to work. (Xcode 10.2.1, Swift 4.2/ 5..)

Comment: How can I make something like this, but inherit the size of the collection view cell?