# Creating a horizontal scrolling with UIViews

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

First start with an example:
[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

It is a bout the bottom part of the images, I can scroll through those small tumbnails on the bottom by swiping.

I am searching for ways to create the effect which is currently used by WhatsApp to scroll through a set of images.

I started by looking how to use a UITableView for this, but I soon bumped into topics about UIScrollView and UICollectionView. Now my question is, what should I use in this case? What is best programming practice in this case.

Should I use an UITableView with custom cells (UIViews) and somehow get it scrolling horizontally.
Should I use an UIScrollView? Most of the tutorials where about showing too large images, so maybe I shouldn't use that one?
Or should I use an UICollectionView? Most of the tutorials about this topic where with 2d grids, so maybe a collectionview is a little overkill?

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you using storyboards?

Comment: answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15167037/4114683

Comment: @Daljeet Yes I use storyboard when I can, is this also possible in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a combination of UICollectionView and UICollectionViewFlowLayout. This post gives you the exact code. [Creating a UICollectionView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically)

For your case, before you init the collectionView with the layout, you'll want to set the scroll direction on the layout so that you can scroll horizontally. Like so:

```
[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
```

In addition, you'll want to set the size of the collection view cells to fit what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is take IBOutlet of scrollview that is  scrollViewForImages

Add the below code and call the function by passing your image array like this:

```
 if (imageArray.count)
    {
        [self addImagesToScrollView:imageArray];
    }
```

and write this code in .m

```
-(void)addImagesToScrollView:(NSArray *)imageArray
{


 CGRect pageFrame;
 UIImageView *imageView;
 CGFloat widthImg = 100.0f;
 CGFloat Dist = 15.0f;


 // scrollVIewForMutualFriends.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

 for (UIView *view in scrollViewForSports.subviews)
 {
     if ( [view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] || [view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]  )
     {
         [view removeFromSuperview];
     }
 }

 for (int i= 0;  i < imageArray.count ; i++) //imageArray.count
 {
 UIView *viewBg = [[UIView alloc] init];

 pageFrame = CGRectMake(i * widthImg , 0.0f, widthImg , widthImg) ;//scrollVIewForMutualFriends.bounds.size.height

 [viewBg setFrame:pageFrame];

 [viewBg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

 [viewBg addSubview: lblName] ;
 [viewBg addSubview:btnOnImg];

 [scrollViewForImages addSubview: viewBg] ;
     }

    scrollViewForImages.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageArray.count * widthImg, scrollViewForSports.frame.size.height);

}
```

let me know if there is any confusion

Comment: Thanks for the code example! I don't know objective c but I suppose I can figure that out myself. Is this also possible with some autolayout for the subviews? Ive build everything else in storybuilder.